# Buttons look ugly on a Windows GUI app (instead of windows native)

Tags: c, windows, win32gui

I am making a simple Windows GUI app using C. But the UI elements looks very ugly (like from 1990) instead of the native Windows 7 controls that I would normally expect. Why is that? What do I need to do to get the native Windows 7 controls? (I'm using Windows 7)

Also I'm wondering about

1. Why do the title bars look Windows 7 native (with transparency) instead of old style?
2. But the rest of controls look old?

Here is my C program

```
#include <windows.h>

int STDCALL;

WinMain (HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow)
{
    MessageBox (NULL, "Hello, Windows!", "Hello", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

The result looks like the 2 windows on the top. But I'm expecting it to look like the one on the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I would assume that the sort answer is that this is the default. You ask your OS to design 2 windows but maybe you need to ask it to decorate them?

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis how do you ask the OS to decorate it natively?

Comment: I am looking right now(lunchbrake) tbh. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Nothing in there about native control styles

Comment: Google "c++ enable visual styles" to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm using C, do you have working code?

Comment: It does not require code, merely a manifest.  Be sure to google it.

Comment: Unrelated, `int STDCALL;` will only declare an integer `STDCALL`, that's not what you want. Use instead `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, ...)`, where `WINAPI` is usually defined as `_stdcall`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the comments and pointing me in the right direction, I solved it by adding a `appname.exe.manifest` file and then re-compiling my program and it now has Windows 7 native style instead of the classic style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"
        name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication" type="win32"/>
    <description>Your application description here.</description>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                version="6.0.0.0" type="win32" processorArchitecture="*"
                publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: You welcome. Did you start looking at this after : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5253279/Create-An-Awesome-WPF-UI-for-Your-Cplusplus-QT-App ?